# html this.id to function not working angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, function

I'm trying to send the id of a element from html to the function, this because it changes in the ts, so I have a click function but function(this.id) doesnt work
here is my code

the html

```
<button id="btnNext" class="btn" (click)="nextGeneral(this.id)">next</button>
```

the ts

```
nextGeneral(id:number){
alert(id)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `id` attribute from the `<button>` (i.e. `btnNext`) to be passed into the `nextGeneral()` function (although this function is currently expecting a `number` not a `string`, so correct me if I'm wrong).

This is how you could achieve that dynamically:

`.html`

```
<button id="btnNext" class="btn" (click)="nextGeneral($event)">next</button>
```

`.ts`

```
nextGeneral(event: PointerEvent){
  const id: string = (event.target as HTMLElement).id
  alert(id)
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, also you where right i neaded a string for id jejeje sorry about that and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not available inside a template. You might want to use 'btnNext' as the parameter instead, but its too vague from your description.

So replace the template's `(click)=nextGeneral(this.id)` with `(click)=nextGeneral('btnNext')` and it will work and also might fit your requirements. Does it fit?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csbctn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: The id that the button has changes, so it wont be btnNext, it could be btnNext_1 and so on

Comment: is `btnNext` a variable of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

One of the cleanest way to achieve it is by using template reference in angular.

```
<button id="btnNext" #myButton class="btn" (click)="nextGeneral(myButton)">next</button>
```

Inside your `nextGeneral`

```
nextGeneral(button: HTMLButtonElement) {
    alert(button.getAttribute('id'));
  }
```

Running Solution - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ohxfa5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts